# The meaning of "at the Governor-General’s rout"

Tags: meaning

> She had been most gracious to me **at the Governor-General’s rout**, and indeed I was looked upon by all as her preux chevalier—which is French for a much worse word. Now, whether I cared so much as the scratch of a pin for this same Mrs. Vansuythen (albeit I had vowed eternal love three days after we met) I knew not then nor did till later on; but mine own pride, and a skill in the small sword that no man in Calcutta could equal, kept me in her affections. So that I believed I worshipt her.

This is from "The Dream of Duncan Parrenness " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/readers-guide/rg_parrenness_notes.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
**at the Governor-General’s rout**.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 4):

The Governor-General was the British monarch's chief representative in India at the time of the Raj.

A rout is **a large evening party or reception** [[Lexico. Definition 3]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rout).

As the dictionary says, the usage is archaic, though the word is still occasionally heard today [in the UK]. It is - and always was - an amusing way to describe a party, bringing with it a flavour of its original meanings:

*gang of outlaws or rioters, mob* [[Etymonline]](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=rout)

and particularly:

*a disorderly retreat of defeated troops*! [Lexico. Definition 2.1](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rout)

Comment: Thank very much for your  perfect answer!!

Comment: @Hiroshi Inagaki:どういたしまして

Comment: I've never heard or seen 'rout' used to mean 'a large evening party or reception' except in Kipling, so I would agree with Lexico that it is 'archaic'.

Comment: I don't think I disagreed with Lexico. It's "_no longer in everyday use but sometimes used to impart an old-fashioned flavour_" [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/archaic).

Comment: Note that the story is written in an imitation of 18th century style.